# 2d arr explicitpackage

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I've looked through several threads on websites including this one to try and understand why I am getting an undeclared variable error for my usage of my $line . Each element of the @lines array is an array of strings.

The error is in line 25 and 27 with the $line[$count] statement

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines;
my @sizes;

# read input from stdin file into 2d array
while(<>)
{
    push(@lines, my @tokens = split(/\s+/, $_));
}

# search through each array for largest sizes in
# corresponding elements
for (my $count = 0; $count <= 5; $count++)
{
    push(@sizes, 0);
    foreach my $line (@lines)
    {   
        if(length($line[$count])>$sizes[$count])
        {
            $sizes[$count] = length($line[$count]);
        }
    }
}
```

I can post the full code if it is necessary, but I am pretty sure the error must be in here somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
push(@lines, my @tokens = split(/\s+/, $_));
```

Pushing one array into another just adds all elements to the first array.  So you are making a really long one dimensional array.

To fix this, use brackets to make an array reference:

```
push @lines, [ split(/\s+/, $_) ]; #No need for a temp variable.
```

Also, to access the array reference, you have to de-reference it.  Both of these syntaxes are options:

```
    ${$line}[$count];
    $line->[$count];
```

I think the second syntax is more readable.

**Update:**  Also, you could simplify your code if you keep track of the longest lengths while you go through the file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/max/;

my @lines;
my @sizes = (0)x6;
while(<>)
{
    push @lines, [ my @tokens = split ];
    @sizes = map { max ( length($tokens[$_]), $sizes[$_] ) } 0..$#tokens;    
}
```

*Note:* The `Data::Dumper` core module is an invaluable tool when working with complex data structures in Perl.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @lines;
```

This will print out the complete structure of whatever variable you give it.  That way you can see if you actually created what you thought you did.

Comment: Yea, I'd drop the parentheses on `split` too.

Comment: @Qtax, well you could just use `[ split ]`.

Comment: Sure, if you want to go that far. But you removed parenthesis on `push` but not `split`, when you can do that just fine. Seems inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information. I'm taking an introductory class in scripting and its taking time getting used to the differences between this and c++/java